# how to run logic on a dynamic schedule?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a UI with a field "date" which is of type LocalDateTime. how to run my logic at given time?
I'm looking for a prettier solution than using @Scheduled to run every second

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/SchedulingConfigurer.html

Using **SchedulingConfigurer** you can keep the scheduling of your job dynamic.